# PM2 - Process or Namespace not found when deploying with GitLab CI

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab, pm2

When deploying from CI, as the user who started PM2, `pm2 restart appname` always results in `[PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace appname not found`

whoami/who on deployment shows the correct user.

Tried switching users, as well as PM2's location:
`/usr/local/bin/pm2 restart appname`
results in the same process not found.

CI command:

```
script:
- pm2 restart appname
```

or:

```
deploy: 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_IP "pm2 restart appname"'
script:
- "eval $deploy"
```

Comment: killing the processes via ssh, then ```pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js``` via CI, did the trick

Answer (score 0):

After the first "pm2 start appname" command run "pm2 save" it will synchronize the process with the previously saved list.
In the CI script include "pm2 save" after restart
example:

- run: sudo pm2 restart appname
- run: sudo pm2 save
  This worked for me, hope you've find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive [PM2][ERROR] Script not found: /root/appname

Run the following first:
pm2 start npm --name "appname" -- run "start:dev"

Then, see/run above from Debapriya Das, pm2 start appname and pm2 save